# Are there any known examples of groups that virtually split that don't have a codimension-1 subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Are there any known examples of groups that virtually split that don't have a codimension-1 subgroup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For a finitely generated group, the property "have no codimension 1 subgroup" is called Property FW. Property FW passes to finite index subgroups, so excludes virtual splittings.

Actually for an infinitely generated group, the existence of a "codimension 1 subgroup", the transitive version of Property FW, is still discarded by virtual splittings, but there are maybe a few details to check. I'll assume in the absence of context that you're interested by finitely generated groups.

Edit: here are missing references. That Property FW passes to finite index subgroups is Proposition 5.B.1 in [this arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5982). The non-existence of a "codimension 1 subgroup" is called Property FW' (and equivalent to Property FW for finitely generated groups, but not in general). That is passes to finite index subgroups is obtained by a similar argument. The whole point is that when one induces an action of a finite index subgroup to the whole group (see §4.F in the above reference), this maps a transitive action to an action with finitely many orbits. I don't use CAT(0) cube complexes for this.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Yves' answer, here are a few details. So the statement is:

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be a (not necessarily finitely-generated) group and $H \subset G$ a finite-index subgroup. If $H$ contains a codimension-one subgroup, then so does $G$.

The first step is Niblo and Roller's theorem: A group contains a codimension-one subgroup if and only if its acts fixed-point freely on a connected cube with a single orbit of hyperplanes (*Groups acting on cubes and Kazhdan's property (T)*, 1998). The second step is notice that an action of the entire group on a CAT(0) cube complex can be constructed from such an action of a finite-index subgroup. I think that the idea of the construction goes back to Serre's article *Cohomologie des groupes discrets* (1971).

**Proposition:** Let $G$ be a group, $H \subset G$ an finite-index subgroup. Suppose that $H$ acts fixed-point freely on some CAT(0) cube complex $X$. Then $G$ acts fixed-point freely on $X^{[G:H]}$.

**Proof.** Consider the set
$$\mathrm{Hom}_H(G,X) = \{ f : G  \to X \mid \forall h \in H, \forall g \in G, \ f(hg)=h \cdot f(g) \}.$$
$G$ acts on $\mathrm{Hom}_H(G,X)$ via:
$$g \cdot f : x \mapsto f(g^{-1}x).$$
Fixing some representatives $G=Ha_1 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup Ha_r$, the map
$$\varphi(a_1, \ldots,a_r) : \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} \mathrm{Hom}_H(G,X) & \to & \prod\limits_{i=1}^r X=X^{[G:H]} \\ f & \mapsto & (f(a_1), \ldots, f(a_r)) \end{array} \right.$$
is a bijection. Notice that, if $b_1, \ldots, b_r$ are other representatives, then
$$\varphi(b_1, \ldots, b_r) \varphi(a_1, \ldots, a_r)^{-1} : (x_1, \ldots, x_r) \mapsto (h_1x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, h_r x_{\sigma(r)}),$$
where $\sigma : \{1, \ldots, r \} \to \{1,\ldots,r\}$ is a permutation and $h_1, \ldots, h_r$ elements of $H$ such that $b_i=h_ia_{\sigma(i)}$ for every $1 \leq i \leq r$. Consequently, if we endow $X^{[G:H]}$ with its natural cubical structure, then then the previous map is an isomorphism.

The conclusion is that, thanks to $\varphi(a_1, \ldots, a_r)$, you can transfer the action $G \curvearrowright \mathrm{Hom}_H(G,X)$ to an action $G \curvearrowright X^{[G:H]}$ by isometries. Finally, notice that this action does not fix a point if $H \curvearrowright X$ is fixed-point free. $\square$

**Remark:** In the statement of the proposition, it is possible to replace "fixed-point freely" with "properly", but not with "geometrically" (see for instance the Coxeter group I mention [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181863/cat0-groups-that-does-not-act-on-cat0-cubical-complex/295487#295487)).

Now the theorem can be proved. Suppose that $H$ contains a codimension subgroup. Then $H$ acts fixed-point freely on a connected cube $X$ with a single orbit of hyperplanes, and we deduce from the construction given in the previous proposition that $G$ acts fixed-point freely on $X^{[G:H]}$, which is also a connected cube. It follows from the definition of this action that $X^{[G:H]}$ contains at most $[G:H]$ orbits of hyperplanes. Choose carefully one of them, say $\mathcal{W}$, so that the action of $G$ on the new CAT(0) cube complex $Y$, obtained by cubulating the wallspace $\left( X^{[G:H]}, \mathcal{W} \right)$, is also fixed-point free. The conclusion follows from the observation that $Y$ is again a connected cube, and that by construction it contains a single $G$-orbit of hyperplanes.

Comment: Niblo-Roller's theorem: I doubt it holds for infinitely generated groups. A counterexample ($\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Q})$) seems to be given by Theorem 1.17 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1318

Comment: If I translate Property FW' in the world of cube complexes, does it mean that I am considering actions with a single orbit of hyperplanes or of halfspaces? My first guess would be the latter case, which may be different from the former one. Also, is it clear that $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Q})$ contains a codimension-one subgroup?

Comment: Probably this is the restatement? I don't understand the second question, since precisely the reference says that $SL_3(Q)$ has Property FW', i.e., has no "codimension 1 subgroup". (I always use quotation marks since this is a counterintuitive and confusing terminology.)

Comment: The point I do not understand is why, if a group $G$ satisfying Property FW' acts on a connected cube $C$ with a single orbit of hyperplanes, then the action $G \curvearrowright C$ must fix a point. I guess the begining of the proof should be as follows: Fix a vertex $v \in C$ and a halfspace $D$ containing $v$. $G$ acts on $G \cdot D$ by commensurating the subset $V$ of halfspaces containing $v$. Property FW' implies that the action is transfixed. If $V$ is infinite, I agree that $G$ fixes $v$. Otherwise, if $V$ is finite, how do you conclude?

Comment: Prop: $G$ acts on a conn. cubing. Let $B_v$ be the set of halfspaces containing $v$. Then $G$ fixes a point iff $B_v$ is transfixed. Indeed, since $|gB_v\Delta B_v|=2d(v,gv)$, $B_v$ is transfixed $\Leftrightarrow$ $g\mapsto |gB_v\Delta B_v|$ is bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ $g\mapsto 2d(v,gv)$ is bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ there's a fixed point.

Comment: (By the way in an infinite cubing, for every vertex $v$, $B_v$ is infinite. Indeed, since $v\mapsto B_v$ is injective, the set of halfplanes is infinite, and this set equals $B_v\cup B_v^*$, where $B_v^*=\{H^c:H\in B_v\}$).

Comment: Here, I am not looking at $B_v$ but the orbit $G \cdot D$ since I need a transitive action to apply Property FW'. But anyway your remark implies the desired conclusion. So I agree that, if $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Q})$ satisfies Property FW', then it cannot act fixed-point freely on a connected cube with a single orbit of hyperplanes. But how do you know that it must contain a codimension-one subgroup? From the fact that it acts fixed-point freely on a CAT(0) cube complex?

Comment: I'm confused. How do you define a "codimension 1 subgroup"? I view it as a subgroup $H\subset G$ such that $G$ commensurates an infinite coinfinite subset of $G/H$. Property FW' precisely means there is no such subgroup.

Comment: For me, a subgroup $K \subset G$ has codimension one if there exists some set $A \subset G$ such that: (i) $A=KA$; (ii) $A$ is $K$-almost invariant, ie., the symmetric difference $A \Delta Ag$ is $K$-finite for every $g \in G$; (iii) $A$ is $K$-proper, ie., neither $A$ nor $G \backslash A$ is $K$-finite.

Comment: OK, this is the negation of Property FW' (sorry the if apostrophe is not well visible). Then I don't understand your last question "how do you know that [$SL_3(Q)$] has a codimension 1 subgroup?". I'm precisely stating that there's none.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your original comment. In which sense is $SL_3(\mathbb{Q})$ a counter-example to Niblo and Roller's theorem? The group does not contain any codimension-one subgroup and does not act fixed-point freely on a connected cube with a single orbit of hyperplanes.

Comment: OK sorry my first comment is not correct (and in the sequel of the conversation I forgot what I said in my first comment...). $SL_3(\mathbf{Q})$ is a counterexample to $\Leftarrow$ of the equivalence (holding for f.g. groups) [has a "codimension-1" subgroup] $\Leftrightarrow$ [has a fixed-point-free action on a nonempty CAT(0) cube complex], which I misread as "Niblo-Roller theorem" (forgetting the fact about a single orbit of hyperplanes).

Comment: And actually the NR theorem can be proved in a few lines. If $H$ has "codimension 1" in $G$, let $M\subset G/H$ be a commensurated subset, neither finite nor cofinite; then the canonical action on $\{f\in\{0,1\}^{G/H}:f-1_M\in\{0,1\}^{(G/H)}\}$ is the desired one. Conversely if $G$ acts on a CCC with a single orbit, say $G/H$, of hyperplanes, and no fixed point, then $H$ has "codimension 1".